# Optimizing SQL duplicate search

Tags: mysql

We are working on a table with roughly 13 million rows. Our goal is to look for duplicates within this table for only one restaurant (~300,000 rows). Our criteria for duplicates are same last name, same first 2 letters of first name, and same phone or email. Each of these are their own column. Our strategy for now is to create two identical, temporary tables for all rows from the restaurant and then to join them on the criteria above and then return id, first name, last name, phone, and email from the first table.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT t1.id, t1.firstname, t1.lastname, t1.phone, t1.email
FROM 
(
    SELECT lmoc.id, lmoc.firstname, lmoc.lastname, lmoc.phone, lmoc.email
    FROM loyalty_member_opentable_customer lmoc
    WHERE lmoc.opentable_restaurant_id=2296 
      AND lmoc.lastname NOT LIKE '%Tour%' 
) AS t1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT lmoc2.id, lmoc2.firstname, lmoc2.lastname, lmoc2.phone, lmoc2.email
    FROM loyalty_member_opentable_customer lmoc2
    WHERE lmoc2.opentable_restaurant_id=2296 
      AND lmoc2.lastname NOT LIKE '%Tour%' 
) AS t2 
   ON STRCMP(t1.lastname,t2.lastname)=0 
  AND t1.id!=t2.id 
  AND STRCMP(LEFT(t1.firstname,2),LEFT(t2.firstname,2))=0 
  AND (STRCMP(t1.phone,t2.phone)=0 OR STRCMP(t1.email,t2.email)=0)
ORDER BY t1.lastname, t1.firstname
```

The issue is that this query takes north of 48 hours to run. Can anybody think of a more efficient way to run this? We need all of the duplicates so that the restaurant could combine them as they see fit.

Comment: Sounds like a good strategy. Have fun.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no question as such.

Comment: It would be useful if you publish the table structure, and the SQL query. Also, some information about current performance would be of help in measuring where it could be improved. Try to rephrase it as a question.

Comment: holy mother of unformatted queries.... you need to look at how to ask a question ... aka provide some data to understand the issue.. provide a formatted query that you can read.. and give an expected output

Comment: You are not creating a temporary table but using subqueries and that will be slow with 13 million rows.  Create a single _real_ temporary table with all the data you need (`SELECT INTO`).

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do

```
SELECT lmoc.lastname, lmoc.firstname, lmoc.phone, lmoc.email
FROM loyalty_member_opentable_customer lmoc
WHERE lmoc.opentable_restaurant_id=2296 
  AND lmoc.lastname NOT LIKE '%Tour%'
GROUP BY lmoc.lastname, LEFT(lmoc.firstname, 2), lmoc.phone, lmoc.email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

?

Comment: This eliminates the either phone or email matching aspect of the criteria. Some duplicates have matching phones and some duplicates have matching emails, but few have both. We also want to have the ID's of both duplicates so that we can combine them.

Answer (score 1):

This SQL will help you find the duplicates

```
SELECT lmoc.id, lmoc.firstname, lmoc.lastname, lmoc.phone, lmoc.email
FROM loyalty_member_opentable_customer lmoc
WHERE lmoc.opentable_restaurant_id=2296 
  AND lmoc.lastname NOT LIKE '%Tour%' 
  AND lmoc.lastname BETWEEN 'ha' AND 'i'
GROUP BY lmoc.opentable_restaurant_id, lmoc.id, LEFT(lmoc.firstname,2), lmoc.lastname, lmoc.phone, lmoc.email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If you got a primary key, they you can easily keep the recent one and purge the old ones, with this SQL

```
DELETE 
        lmoc.primary_id
FROM loyalty_member_opentable_customer lmoc
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        MAX(lmoc.primary_id) AS id
    FROM loyalty_member_opentable_customer lmoc
    WHERE lmoc.opentable_restaurant_id=2296 
        AND lmoc.lastname NOT LIKE '%Tour%' 
        AND lmoc.lastname BETWEEN 'ha' AND 'i'
    GROUP BY lmoc.opentable_restaurant_id, lmoc.id, LEFT(lmoc.firstname,2), lmoc.lastname, lmoc.phone, lmoc.email
    ) nodup 
    ON adjuster.id = nodup.id
WHERE lmoc.opentable_restaurant_id=2296 
        AND lmoc.lastname NOT LIKE '%Tour%' 
        AND lmoc.lastname BETWEEN 'ha' AND 'i'
        AND nodup.id IS NULL";
```

Comment: I don't get the `lmoc.lastname BETWEEN 'ha' AND 'i'`?

Comment: I just took that WHERE condition from Zak's question. Seems like he edited it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating a temporary table but using subqueries and that will be slow with 13 million rows. Create a single real temporary table with all the data you need (`SELECT INTO`).

This is what I'd try :

```
/* Creating a temporary table */
SELECT lmoc.id, lmoc.firstname, lmoc.lastname, lmoc.phone, lmoc.email
INTO tempRestaurant
FROM loyalty_member_opentable_customer AS lmoc
WHERE
  lmoc.opentable_restaurant_id=2296 AND
  lmoc.lastname NOT LIKE '%Tour%' 

/* Select duplicates */
SELECT * FROM 
  tempRestaurant AS t1 
INNER JOIN tempRestaurant AS t2 ON 
  STRCMP(t1.lastname,t2.lastname)=0 
  AND t1.id!=t2.id 
WHERE
  STRCMP(LEFT(t1.firstname,2), LEFT(t2.firstname,2))=0 AND
  ( STRCMP(t1.phone,t2.phone)=0 OR STRCMP(t1.email,t2.email)=0 )
```